# Cover picture offset_y too big

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph's API to get cover pictures and place them in my app.

I'm using the offset_y property to position the picture and almost all of the times this works, but in some other cases the API is returning values that seem too big, for example sometimes it returns 78, 82 even 100.

Am I missing something? I understand that these values are percentages so how can the offset be 100%?

Thanks for your answers